# Can an unskewed distribution be expressed as product of a normal and another distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, gaussian, cumulants

Let $x$ be a continuous random variable with zero mean and zero skew. What are the conditions under which we can say that $x$ can be expressed as the product $z y$ where $z$ is a standard normal and $y$ is a strictly positive random variable independent of $z$? I don't think, for example, that unimodality is required, but I think we do require that the CDF of $x$ be continuous, say (no point masses). Are there other conditions?

Comment: OK, duh, well $x$ has to have zero odd centered moments, which is a bit of a restriction.

Comment: You should realy add that info to the OP not as a comment!

Comment: The moments don't necessarily exist, but the distribution is symmetric about $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic function of $x$ is $\varphi(s) = \mathbb E[e^{isx}] = \mathbb E[e^{-s^2 y^2/2}]$.  The fact that $\varphi(s) \to 0$ as $s \to \pm \infty$ tells you that $x$ is continuous.